# What is the best speed optimization for Joomla based Social network (Easysocial)?

Tags: .htaccess, cdn, joomla3.0, varnish, easyblog

I am building (development phase) a Social Network site on Joomla 3 with  Easysocial, Easyblog and EasyDiscuss as main extensions, using it on a  shared host which has Varnish cache (static+dynamic) enabled and I am  looking forward to use AWS storage and CDN.
My  question is : What is the best speed optimization could be in this  scenario. As main component would be creating dynamic content by users  frequently and some instant features like chat, like, comment, friend request etc is  included .
Previously I have  activated CloudFlare free version to test leaving default settings and  some features either was not working or working after 2-3 min. Please  suggest me ? Also if possible suggest possible cache time, htaccess config, Etag options etc, whatever needed.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Install memcached - this will speed up a little, few times at least